# What tool/library can help me to generate and test model of neural network that would work with X*Y int arrays as input and N*4 int arrays as output?

Tags: c++, scripting, generator, neural-network

I want to make simple neural network that from given gray-scale 2d arrays like

```
[[1 1 1]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
```

would give me line coordinates

```
[[1 2]
 [3 2]]
```

I have a C++ program that has a real algorithm in it to compute lines from gray-scale images and a large set of images. I need some NN tool wit scripting language so that I could generate a program to teach and generate NN. so I could create some programm with structure like:

```
generateNN(NN);
NN.provideData(WxHGSImageArray);
NN.provideDesiredResult(2PointsLineArray);
```

So... Is there any such C++/C lib for generation of NNs or any programmable tool with scripting language?

Main problem here is - what tool/lib supports creation of systems that can take X*Y arrays and output N*4 arrays (N - number of lines found on image)? (btw X and Y are different for different images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quite comprehensive list of nn simulators:
[Comparison of Neural Network Simulators](http://grey.colorado.edu/emergent/index.php/Comparison_of_Neural_Network_Simulators)

Answer (score 2):

Try [SNNS](http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/SNNS/). It is a great software package for simulating neural networks. A JNNS version of the toolsuite is also available. It is called [JavaNNS](http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/downloads/JavaNNS/).

I've used the SNNS and JavaNNS for neural networks simulations and it was very useful. It has a steep learning curve, but it's certainly worth trying!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a C++ neural network library you're comfortable with, you might try writing a small binding for lua (take a look at [toalua++](http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/) in this case) or Python ([SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is a good option).

Of course, if the API is too big with might not be worth the effort.

Comment: That is the problem - I have an app I wrote in C++ that uses standard math algorithms to find lines on gray scaled images. I need some NN lib/tool to create a NN from results and data I use in my app.

Comment: @Kabumbus Why not just use a C++ NN library then? I've used this http://user.cs.tu-berlin.de/~nowozin/libpn/ for a few experiments.